# How to get the distinct elements from a python list?

Tags: python

My list is like this: `[['a','b'],['c','a'],['k','f'],['s','b'],['a','b']...]`
I want to get a new list which has no duplicate elements from it. What is the fastest way to realize it ?

Comment: By 'duplicate elements', are you referring to the inner lists (ex: `['a', 'b']`), or to the individual elements (ex: `'a'`)?

Answer (score 1):

Using sets; first you need to cast the inner lists to non mutable types (tuples):

```
uniques = set(tuple(elt) for elt in ([['a','b'],['c','a'],['k','f'],['s','b'],['a','b']]))
```

#### output

```
{('a', 'b'), ('c', 'a'), ('k', 'f'), ('s', 'b')}
```

Please note that sets will not preserve the order of the elements.